# Laravel Eloquent update cannot see columns that needs to be updated

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

**Hello guys, I created a "promos" table and now, I am working on the CRUD functionalities of this module. The "create" functionality is done and I encountered no problems. My only problem is this when I am updating my model and it is very weird.**

It seems that $this->model->where('id', $id)->first() cannot see and retrieve the list of columns. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

I already tried composer dump-autoload and php artisan clear-compiled hoping the problem will fix itself.

For additional reference, here is my schema, model and code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Other notes: $this->model points to the Promo model*

---

**EDIT:**

I did not display the controllers specifically the update method as stated by @OmarTarek. Our company is using RepositoryInterface Pattern. Instead of the normal **View=>Controller=>Model** when saving data to the database, our workflow is like this **View=>Controller=>Repository=>Model**

In my controller, my code is

[image]

While in my repository, my code is like this:

[image]

As you can see, I am inheriting the BaseRepository.php because it has all the necessary functions/methods for create, update and delete.

It is the BaseRepository
[image]

I highlighted the code that is giving the error.

---

**EDIT II:**

I already implemented the change suggested by @PaladiN. The error still displays and the update method still don't work.

[image]

Comment: A few questions, why aren't you referencing the model as $promo = Promo::where('id', $id)->first();? Also where is the $id variable coming from? Can you post the whole Update() method of your controller? You are using a controller for CRUD right?

Comment: Try this `$this->model::find($id);`

Comment: this might work `$this->model->where('id', $id)->select(["id"])->first()`

Comment: @OmarTarek , no, I am not using a controller. We are using RepositoryInterface Pattern here in my work. The update method is found in the repository, not in the controllers.

Comment: I cannot see `$fillable` field in your model. Could you try adding the fillable field and add all the fillable columns over there and try once.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `first()` since the id is a primary key. Also you're calling the update statement again on `updateData()` method, you should remove that.

```
$this->model->where($key, $value)->update($data);
```

Also when you either define $fillable or $guarded, not both. When you define $guarded with an empty array, all the fields become fillable by default. Another thing would be to check if the model created in the constructor using make() is a valid model instance before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late update. I just fixed this error but I still don't know how this error happened. It seems that a mutator from our BaseModel.php interferes with the updating of data.

[image]

I tried overriding the mutator in my Promo.php model to make the update method work and the error no longer shows.

I still don't know what caused the error but I am eager to deliver this module first to our clients so I will investigate how this scenario happened next time.

Thanks guys.